# javascript. Label for element with generated ID

Tags: javascript, asp.net, label

I would like to do this

```
<label class="test" for="myButton" >This is a label</label>
<input type="button" id="myButton" value="click me" />
```

for some buttons in a page that receive IDs on page load: genereated server side (asp 3.5).

How do I get the right id in the 'for' attribute of the label element for each button?

Thanks

Comment: You've written software to generate the ID. Your software knows what that ID is. Use that to programatically populate the `for` attribute too.

Comment: Quentin, you are right. Afzalulh gave the code for it. And it works like a charm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `AssociatedControlID` property of `Label`:

```
<asp:Label  class="test" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="myButton">
   This is a label</asp:Label>
<asp:Button ID="myButton" runat="Server" Text="click me" />
```

Source: [AssociatedControlID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.label.associatedcontrolid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Perfect afzalulh! You saved my day :-)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<label class="test" for="<%= myButton.ClientID %>" >This is a label</label>
<input type="button" id="myButton" runat="server" value="click me" />
```

this will use the same id generated by asp.net on the server side

Comment: Thanks JBB for answering. This generates error BC30451 (it does not recognise myButton)

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the input tag inside of the label tags and will not require a for/id

```
<label>This is a label <input type="button"/></label>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, jlzavitz. This gave me an error: BC3045.